# Get summarized value of a column based on the range of date across a year using spark rdd and spark dataframes

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe df1 like below

| product | start | end | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 6/12/2020 | 6/7/2021 | 12 |
| p1 | 6/8/2021 | 10/19/2021 | 14 |
| p1 | 10/20/2021 | 5/14/2022 | 13 |
| p1 | 5/15/2022 | 11/20/2022 | 12.5 |
| p1 | 11/21/2022 | 1/1/2099 | 12.5 |
| p2 | 6/12/2017 | 6/7/2021 | 12 |
| p2 | 6/8/2021 | 10/19/2021 | 14 |
| p2 | 10/20/2021 | 5/14/2022 | 12 |
| p2 | 5/15/2022 | 5/14/2099 | 11 |

i am trying to calculate the average price by year for 2021,2022,2023 and looking for the output dataframe like below

| product | year | average price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 2021 | 12.18 |
| p1 | 2022 | 12.61 |
| p1 | 2023 | 12.5 |
| p2 | 2021 | 12.63 |
| p2 | 2022 | 13.77 |
| p2 | 2023 | 11 |

### Calculation

**Product P1  Year 2021**

((6/7/2021 - 1/1/2021)*12 + (10/19/2021 - 6/8/2021) + (12/12/2021 - 10/20/2021))/365

= (158 *12 + 133 * 14 + 53 * 13)/365
= 12.18

**Product P1  Year 2022**

((5/14/2022 - 1/1/2022) * 13 + (11/20/22 - 5/15/2022) + (12/12/2022 - 11/21/2022))

=134*13 + 189 * 12.5 + 40 * 12.5

=12.61

**Product P1  Year 2023**

=12.5

There is no change in price since 11/21/2022, so the value remained same for 2023.

---

I have tried converting the df1 as RDD and tried doing it using map function, but not able to completely achieve the desired results. So any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**PySpark**

First, I read your sample data and change the format of the start, end columns to the date.

```
df = spark.read.csv('test.tsv', sep='\t', inferSchema=True, header=True) \
  .withColumn('start', f.to_date('start', 'M/d/y')) \
  .withColumn('end', f.to_date('end', 'M/d/y'))
df.show()

+-------+----------+----------+-----+
|product|     start|       end|price|
+-------+----------+----------+-----+
|     p1|2020-06-12|2021-06-07| 12.0|
|     p1|2021-06-08|2021-10-19| 14.0|
|     p1|2021-10-20|2022-05-14| 13.0|
|     p1|2022-05-15|2022-11-20| 12.5|
|     p1|2022-11-21|2099-01-01| 12.5|
|     p2|2017-06-12|2021-06-07| 12.0|
|     p2|2021-06-08|2021-10-19| 14.0|
|     p2|2021-10-20|2022-05-14| 12.0|
|     p2|2022-05-15|2099-05-14| 11.0|
+-------+----------+----------+-----+
```

Second, create the base dataframe to get the year based date range.

```
data = [i for i in range(2020, 2024)]

base_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=IntegerType()).toDF('year') \
  .withColumn('range_start', f.to_date('year', 'y')) \
  .withColumn('range_end', f.expr('range_start + interval 1 year - interval 1 day'))

base_df.show()

+----+-----------+----------+
|year|range_start| range_end|
+----+-----------+----------+
|2020| 2020-01-01|2020-12-31|
|2021| 2021-01-01|2021-12-31|
|2022| 2022-01-01|2022-12-31|
|2023| 2023-01-01|2023-12-31|
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Finally, join these dataframes when the start and end range is overlapped. After that, you have to  restrict the `start` and `end` value in those range. The datediff will loose a day, so add +1 and calculate the average by your own.

```
base_df.join(df, (f.col('range_start') < f.col('end')) & (f.col('start') < f.col('range_end')), 'inner') \
  .withColumn('start', f.greatest('start', 'range_start')) \
  .withColumn('end', f.least('end', 'range_end')) \
  .withColumn('date_diff', f.datediff('end', 'start') + 1) \
  .groupBy('year', 'product') \
  .agg(f.round(f.sum(f.col('date_diff') * f.col('price')) / f.sum('date_diff'), 2).alias('average')) \
  .orderBy('product', 'year') \
  .show()
```